# Relationship returning null in unit test

Tags: unit-test

In a unit test, I'm having a problem where values spanning relationships are blank. I have a custom field, `Quote.My_Formula_Field__c`, which is defined as `Opportunity.Lookup__r.Name`, which is used in a validation rule. This always returns null in my unit test.

Test code snippet:

```
Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(
  Name = 'Test Opp',
  AccountId = testAccount1.Id,
  CloseDate = system.today(),
  StageName = 'Open',
  Lookup__c = testAccount2.Id,
  Pricebook2Id = test.getStandardPricebookId());
insert testOpp;

Quote testQuote = new Quote(
  name = 'Test Quote',
  OpportunityId = testOpp.Id,
  Pricebook2Id = test.getStandardPricebookId(),
  Status = 'Open');
insert testQuote;

testQuote = [SELECT Id, OpportunityId, Opportunity.Lookup__c 
             FROM Quote WHERE Id=:testQuote.Id];


System.debug('Quote.Opp: ' + testQuote.OpportunityId); // testOpp.Id  
System.debug('Opp.Lookup__c:'  : testOpp.Lookup__c); // Lookup__c
System.debug('Quote.Opp.Lookup__c:'  : testQuote.Opportunity.Lookup__c); // null
```

Similar questions:

[Test data fields return null in class but are populated in unit test](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5627/test-data-fields-return-null-in-class-but-are-populated-in-unit-test)

[Why is my reference field returning null my test code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/why-is-my-reference-field-returning-null-my-test-code)

** **Update** **

I added the following two assertions:

```
// This assertion passes
System.assertEquals(testOpp.Id, testQuote.OpportunityId, 'Opportunity does not match.');
// This assert fails; expected NULL, actual [record id]
System.assertEquals(testQuote.Opportunity.Lookup__c, testOpp.Lookup__c, 'Lookup__c does not match.');
```

Comment: What do your CreateTestOpportunity and CreateTestQuote methods do?

Comment: Why do you need the SOQL query for testQuote immediately after getting it from CreateTestQuote?

Comment: @AlexTennant, I expanded out the helper methods inline.

Comment: @jagular, the SOQL is there so I can access fields across the relationship.

Comment: For grins, what happens if you add to your SOQL select on quote some other fields from Opportunity, like Opportunity.name, Opportunity.amount ? Do they assert as null or nonNull?  Have you tried to see if Contact.account.name matches the account's .name field as in your remark to Keith C?

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to reproduce your problem using some added fields in an org and this test:

```
@isTest
private class MyTest {

    @isTest
    static void test() {

        Account testAccount1 = new Account(Name = 'a1');
        insert testAccount1;
        Account testAccount2 = new Account(Name = 'a2');
        insert testAccount2;

        Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(
          Name = 'Test Opp',
          AccountId = testAccount1.Id,
          CloseDate = system.today(),
          StageName = 'Open',
          Lookup__c = testAccount2.Id,
          Pricebook2Id = test.getStandardPricebookId());
        insert testOpp;

        Quote testQuote = new Quote(
          name = 'Test Quote',
          OpportunityId = testOpp.Id,
          Pricebook2Id = test.getStandardPricebookId(),
          Status = 'Open');
        insert testQuote;

        testQuote = [SELECT Id, OpportunityId, Opportunity.Lookup__c, My_Formula_Field__c
                     FROM Quote WHERE Id=:testQuote.Id];

        System.assertNotEquals(null, testQuote.Opportunity);
        System.assertNotEquals(null, testQuote.Opportunity.Lookup__c);
        System.assertNotEquals(null, testQuote.My_Formula_Field__c);
    }
}
```

but the test passes so the problem is in something other than the code posted in the question.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you, but I'm following relationships here (see additional assert statements I added to my question.) This is the same as having Account.Name not match Contact.Account.Name; both are referencing the same field and should have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to your test: `testOpp = [SELECT Id, Lookup__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:testOpp.Id];` You are comparing testQuote after insert results to the testOpp existing test data. There is probably a trigger that is causing that lookup field to become null after the insert.